# CSS3 / HTML5 /Javascript vertical screen resize

Tags: html, css, alignment

I would like one div in my web page to take up the whole area of the screen - vertically and horizontally.

There will be more divs below it.

I got the horizontal part, but I'm not sure how to do the vertical part.
This website does it to an extent: http://ournameismud.co.uk/#

Comment: does it matter to you to use javascript/jquery?

Comment: @Charlie No, I'm fine with using either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the height of the `html` and `body` to 100% and then your `div` to 100% as well.
For Example

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#my-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Edit:** Forgot to set margin and padding to 0.

Comment: This worked after I did some tweaking with my poorly styled elements. Thanks.